# What causes a stack overflow error when the Jenkins job DSL plugin is trying to delete some unreferenced jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I removed some old jobs from the Jenkins job DSL file that was used to create the jobs. While the seed job is running and trying to process the unreferenced jobs by deleting them it fails with a stack overflow error.

Here is an excerpt from the error message:

```
Unreferenced items:
    GeneratedJob{name='...'}
    GeneratedJob{name='...'}
    ... about 20 more Unreferenced jobs listed here ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from ***.***.***.net/***.***.**.**:***** failed
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:237)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Workspaces.getListFromServer(Workspaces.java:36)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Workspaces.populateMapFromServer(Workspaces.java:45)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Workspaces.exists(Workspaces.java:71)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.actions.RemoveWorkspaceAction.remove(RemoveWorkspaceAction.java:25)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.processWorkspaceBeforeDeletion(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:465)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.processWorkspaceBeforeDeletion(SCM.java:245)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.performDelete(AbstractProject.java:358)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem.delete(AbstractItem.java:775)
    at hudson.model.Job.delete(Job.java:675)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder.delete(AbstractFolder.java:1176)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.updateGeneratedJobs(ExecuteDslScripts.java:460)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:361)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from ***.***.***.net/***.***.**.**:***** failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:963)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:233)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.listeners.StandardListenerList$ListenerNode.addListener(StandardListenerList.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.listeners.StandardListenerList$ListenerNode.addListener(StandardListenerList.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.listeners.StandardListenerList$ListenerNode.addListener(StandardListenerList.java:304)
    ... about 500 more lines like this  ...
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.listeners.StandardListenerList$ListenerNode.addListener(StandardListenerList.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.listeners.StandardListenerList$ListenerNode.addListener(StandardListenerList.java:304)
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from ***.***.***.net/***.***.**.**:***** failed
Finished: FAILURE
 Help us localize this pagePage generated: Feb 2, 2020 2:49:10 PM CSTREST APIJenkins ver. 2.177
```

I attempted to fix things by deleting the jobs using the Jenkins UI. I got the same stack overflow error there on a couple of the affected jobs. I changed the source control setting from Team Foundation Server to None, saved the job, and then deleted it. That worked and the jobs are now cleared out.

I went back and ran the seed job again but it still fails with this message.

What causes this stack overflow error in Jenkins while trying to delete jobs?

Comment: How much is 'some jobs'? Maybe there are so many that it exceeds the stack?

Comment: 4 jobs caused this stack overflow. The whole system has about 125 jobs.